# Cascading dropdown columns in Tabulator JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabulator

I am new to the Tabulator JS library and I stumbled upon an issue. I have 2 columns and I am trying to find a way to implement cascading dropdowns in each row. The second column value options are dependent on the first column value selection.  What would be an easy way of doing it?

**Expected results:**

1. User selects **Color** in the first column  and then he should see **Blue & Yellow** in the second column dropdown list of that row.
2. User selects **Style** in the first column and then he should see **S1 & S2** in the second column dropdown list of that row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var tabledata = [{ Need: "1",Surface:"" }];
            var NeedOptionSet = {};
            NeedOptionSet["1"] = "Color";
            NeedOptionSet["2"] = "Style";
            var SurfaceOptionSet_Color = {};
            SurfaceOptionSet_Color["1"] = "Blue";
            SurfaceOptionSet_Color["2"] = "Yellow";
            var SurfaceOptionSet_Style = {};
            SurfaceOptionSet_Style["1"] = "Bold";
            SurfaceOptionSet_Style["2"] = "Underline";
            var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
                height: 400, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
                data: tabledata, //assign data to table
                layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
                pagination: "local",
                paginationSize: 15,
                paginationSizeSelector: [15, 25, 35],
                addRowPos: "top",
                columns: [ //Define Table Columns
                    {
                        title: "Need", field: "Need", editor: "autocomplete", editorParams: {
                            showListOnEmpty: true,
                            freetext: true,
                            values: NeedOptionSet
                        }, formatter: 'lookup', formatterParams: NeedOptionSet

                    },
                    {
                        title: "Surface", field: "Surface", editor: "autocomplete", editorParams: {
                            showListOnEmpty: true,
                            freetext: true,
                            values: SurfaceOptionSet_Color
                        }, formatter: 'lookup', formatterParams: SurfaceOptionSet_Color
                    }
                ]
            });

        });


    </script>

</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="example-table"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need HTML help?

Answer (score -1):

Tabulator has a built in Context Menu system for bringing up cascading menus.

If you want them on each row then you should use the `rowContextMenu` option.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowContextMenu:[
        {
            label:"Delete Row",
            action:function(e, row){
                row.delete();
            }
        },
        {
            label:"Sub Menu" //sub menu
            menu:[
                {
                    label:"Do Something"
                    action:function(e, column){
                        //do something
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
});
```

If you want the values of each menu to change then you can pass a callback to the `rowContextMenu` property that is called each time the menu is loaded, it should return the menu array as outline above:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowContextMenu: function(component, e){
        //component - column/cell/row component that triggered the menu
        //e - click event object

        var menu = [];

        if(!component.getData().approved){
            menu.push({
                label:"Approve User",
                action:function(e, column){
                    component.update({"approved":true});
                }
            })
        }else{
            menu.push({
                label:"Unapprove User",
                action:function(e, column){
                    component.update({"approved":false});
                }
            })
        }

        return menu;
    }
});
```

Full details can be found in the [Context Menu Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/menu#row-context)